# Cómo se trabaja con funciones en SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, funciones

Dentro de los trabajos que he realizado con C# siempre he tenido que trabajar con procedimientos almacenados, pero hoy me pidieron trabajar con una función, que es esta:

```
dbo.fun_cadena_blq(folio_web, rutCliente, 'ABO', 0)
```

Si yo la ejecuto como:

```
select dbo.fun_cadena_blq(546604, '0161636320', 'ABO', 0) as folio_blq
```

En la base de datos me trae el valor que necesito

Tengo la duda de cómo tendría que ejecutar esta consulta desde C# a mi sql, tengo el siguiente código que es como creo que tendría que ser:

```
public int ObtenerCodigoFolioBloqueo(string folioweb, string rut)
{
    SqlCommand var_comando = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter var_adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter();
    int var_resultado = 0;

    try
    {
        abrirconexion();

        var_comando.CommandText = @"select [RENEGOCIACION].[dbo].[FUN_CADENA_BLQ](@num_folio, @num_rut, 'ABO', 0) as valor_blq";
        var_comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num_folio", folioweb);
        var_comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rutCliente", rut);    
        var_comando.Connection = var_conexion;
        var_adaptador.SelectCommand = var_comando;
        
        //--- acá es donde creo que me falta algo

        cerrarconexion();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        
        string err = ex.Message;
        err = "";
    }

    return var_resultado;
}
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Tendrias que hacer un select de la funcion: `var_commanod.CommanText = "select dbo.nombrefunction(@parametro, @parametro)";`

Comment: @CristinaCarrasco estaba pensando como

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select dbo.fun_cadena_bql("+folioweb+","+rut+",'ABO', 1)"

y después ejecutar un SqlReader

Comment: exacto asi deberia de funcionar

Comment: lo voy a probar, gracias

Comment: @CristinaCarrasco hola, modifiqué mi pregunta a cómo la tengo hasta ahora, aunque creo que me falta algo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la función regresa un valor, puedes utilizar [ExecuteScalar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

```
public int ObtenerCodigoFolioBloqueo(int folioweb, string rut)
{
    try
    {
        
        //ejecutar una consulta sobre una función escalar
        string consulta = "Select dbo.fun_cadena_blq(@folio_web, @rutCliente, @abonado, @otroParam);";

        var ConnectionString = this.conectionString; //cadena de conexión a tu base de datos.
        
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            //Inicializa el comando que se va a ejecutar
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, connection))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folio_web", folioweb);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rutCliente", rut);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@abonado", "ABO");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otroParam", 0);

                var valor = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return valor;
            }
        }
        
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlError)
    {
        // manejar sqlException
        throw sqlError;
        
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        // manejar exception
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Pero hay algún matiz. La función escalar SQL, espera un parámetro, que por la ejecución que muestras es un int o similar, y en el código de c# está como string. Yo lo he puesto como int.

El SqlCommand tiene dos maneras de inyectarle los [parámetros](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). Una como te he expuesto, de la manera rápida, donde se determina el tipo por el valor. [AddWithValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).
Y otra mas detallada con [Add](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Es interesante utilizar bloques using, porque se encargan de cerrar liberar los recursos de los objetos creados, y no tienes que encargarte tu en bloques try catch con finally.

Comment: voy a probar tu código y te cuento como me va, muchas gracias

Comment: hola, tengo una duda, en mi código tengo una función para abrir la conexion y otro para cerrarla, cómo tendría que ser para ese caso? Gracias

Comment: Para cerrar la conexion puedes poner un Finally en el try catch y cerrarla en ese momento, miralo en este link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/0e1f2283-50c7-49ff-a88c-fc50b89cbac7/conexion-c-y-sql-server?forum=sqlserveres

Comment: Si, eso ya lo tengo controlado de otra forma, muchas gracias